# Compare size of file system

Tags: shell-script, filesystems, aix, size

How to compare size of file system on 2 different servers
Eg:

```
Server1
Filesystem    GB blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/prddatalv     40.00     18.32   55%       65     1% /u01/oradata/PRD/data

Server2
Filesystem    GB blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/tstdatalv     24.00      7.20   71%       68     1% /u01/oradata/TST/data
```

I need to compare file system size and if Server1 size is greater than Server2 size send a mail alerting saying add space to make size equal.

Comment: Do you have file containing those data like above..or you need to execute command for disk usage..

Answer (score 0):

On server2:

```
[ `ssh server1 "stat -f -c '%b'  /u01/oradata/PRD/data"` -gt `stat -f -c '%b'  /u01/oradata/TST/data` ] && (echo Alert | mail root@wherever )
```

Assuming you have GNU coreutil's `stat(1)` installed.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your reply. Your reply gave me an idea how to approach this. Really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @Radovan Garabik: Sadly AIX does not have gnu stat, it only has [istat](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/istat.htm) which does not support any options.